# Diff markup present in merged file

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

In the Synchronize view, I right click the conflicted file then select `Edit Conflict`. Once I'm done merging the files, I right click the file and select `Mark Merged`.

However, when I open the file in the PHP perspective, I still see the diff markers:

```
<<<<<<< .working
...
=======
```

I then proceed to get rid of them before commiting my code. There has to be a better way... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started using TortoiseSVN for merge operations.